# importing other python file functions not working

Tags: python, function

I have two script one does the work and the other has a function that gives correct values to variables. Anyway I get the following error when calling a function in script(2) using a parameter from script(1)

SCRIPT 1 (PROBLEM WITH LAST LINE COUNT_help.months() :

```
while True:
    day = raw_input("Please Enter The Day: ")
    month = raw_input("Please Enter The Month: ")
    year = raw_input("Please Enter The Year: ")

    if day.isdigit():
        if day > 0:
            correctcheck = "1"
        else:
            print "You Did Not Enter A Valid Day"
            errormsg = "1"
            break
    else:
        print "You Did Not Enter A Valid Day"
        errormsg = "1"
        break

    if month.isdigit():
        if month > 0:
            correctcheck = "2"
        else:
            print "You Did Not Enter A Valid Month"
            errormsg = "1"
            break
    else:
        print "You Did Not Enter A Valid Month"
        errormsg = "1"
        break

    if year.isdigit():
        if year > 0:
            correctcheck = "3"
        else:
            print "You Did Not Enter A Valid Year"
            errormsg = "1"
            break
    else:
        print "You Did Not Enter A Valid Year"
        errormsg = "1"
        break

    if correctcheck == "3":
        COUNT_help.months(months = month)
        print month
        print months
```

SCRIPT 2 :

```
jan = 1
feb = 32
mar = 60
apr = 91
may = 121
jun = 152
jul = 182
aug = 213
sep = 244
obr = 274
nov = 305
dec = 335

def months(months = ""):
    if months == "1":
        months = jan
        return months
    if months == "2":
        months = feb
        return months
    if months == "3":
        months = mar
        return months
    if months == "4":
        months = apr
        return months
    if months == "5":
        months = may
        return months
    if months == "6":
        months = jun
        return months
    if months == "7":
        months = jul
        return months
    if months == "8":
        months = aug
        return months
    if months == "9":
        months = sep
        return months
    if months == "10":
        months = obr
        return months
    if months == "11":
        months = nov
        return months
    if months == "12":
        months = dec
        return months
```

Comment: and what is the problem? Also how are your files connected? where is the import statement?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\COUNT.py", line 60, in <module>
    COUNT_help.months(months = month)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'months'

Comment: How are you importing the second script?

Comment: import COUNT_help   and i have tested it (using a variable print ) to see if it imported and it did.

Comment: I suggest you to change the if statements in the second script with a dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `COUNT_help.months(months = month)` somewhere. Also look into the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) library.

```
if correctcheck == "3": 
    months = COUNT_help.months(months = month) 
    print month 
    print months
```

Comment: That returns This : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\COUNT.py", line 60, in <module>
    months = COUNT_help.months(months = month)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'months

Comment: @Matthew Do you set the `__all__` variable in 'COUNT_help.py' at all? Also, include your original `import` statement above.

Comment: i use import COUNT_help and dont use 1__all__

Comment: using `__all__` i got : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\COUNT.py", line 60, in <module>
    months = months(months = str(month))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @Matthew Then the code you're trying to run is different from what you've posted here. Adding the `import COUNT_help` line to the top of the first script, I don't get an error on the `COUNT_help.months` line.

Comment: @Matthew You don't need to use the `__all__` dictionary for something this simple, but if you do use it incorrectly, it can cause issues like this. If you're not using it at all though, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I just took out the function and added the if statement to script 1. I give Up. LOL